Fetching data in batches: Invalid operation: result set is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=null
I am using JDBC driver (db2jcc4.jar) to connect to IBM DB2 database using the Python jaydebeapi package and trying to fetch table records in batches. I can retrieve all the table records, but after the cursor reaches the end of the result set, it gets closed. When the cursor tries to fetch records again, there are no more records left to retrieve, which I believe causes an error.
import jaydebeapi

class DatabaseConnection:
    def __init__(self, db_host, db_port, db_database, db_user, db_password, db_driver_path, db_driver_class):
        self.db_host = db_host
        self.db_port = db_port
        self.db_database = db_database
        self.db_user = db_user
        self.db_password = db_password
        self.db_driver_path = db_driver_path
        self.db_driver_class = db_driver_class
        self.conn = None
        self.cursor = None

    def connect(self):
        db_url = f"jdbc:db2://{self.db_host}:{self.db_port}/{self.db_database}:allowNextOnExhaustedResultSet=1;"
        # print(f"db pass: {self.db_password}")

        print(f"Connecting to database {self.db_database} at {self.db_host}:{self.db_port}")
        
        try:    
            self.conn = jaydebeapi.connect(
                self.db_driver_class,
                db_url,
                {'user': self.db_user, 'password': self.db_password},
                self.db_driver_path
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error while connecting to database: {e}")
            raise
        
        if self.conn is not None:
            self.conn.jconn.setAutoCommit(True)
            self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            print("Connection established.")
        
    def execute_query(self, query, batch=100):
        if not self.cursor:
            raise Exception("No database connection. Please connect first.")

        try:
            print(f"Executing query: {query}")
            self.cursor.execute(query)

            count = 0
            while True:
                print('Inside while loop...')
                rows = self.cursor.fetchmany(batch)
                if not rows:
                    print("No more records to fetch....")
                    break
                for record in rows:
                    count += 1
                    print(f"{count}: {record}")
                
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error executing query: {e}")
            raise

    def close(self):
        try:
            if self.cursor is not None:
                self.cursor.close()
            if self.conn is not None:
                self.conn.close()
            print("Connection closed.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error closing the connection: {e}")
            raise


I am using this sample query
SELECT * FROM {schema}.{table};
And getting the below error
Inside while loop...
.
.
batch records
.
.
Inside while loop...
.
.
batch records
.
.
Inside while loop...
Error executing query: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][t4][10120][10898][4.33.31] Invalid operation: result set is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=null

I tried providing allowNextOnExhaustedResultSet=1; in the db_url but nothing happened.
db_url = f"jdbc:db2://{self.db_host}:{self.db_port}/{self.db_database}:allowNextOnExhaustedResultSet=1;"

How could I correct this error? Is there any other better way to fetch records in batches? Thanks!!

This question is similar to: Invalid operation result set is closed errorcode 4470 sqlstate null - DB2 data extract. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

According to the docs, other attributes might be necessary, e.g resultSetHoldability.=1;
